# UIView invert mask MaskView

Tags: swift, uiview, mask

I want to apply an inverted mask to my UIView. I set the mask to a UIImageView with a transparent image. However the output with

```
view.mask = imageView
```

is not the desired result. How can I achieve the desired result as I illustrated below? The desired result uses the mask cutout as transparency. When I check the mask of the View, it isn't a CAShapeLayer so I can't invert it that way.

[image: An illustration of what happens vs what I want.]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems like you could do a few things. You could use the image you have but mask a white view and place a blue view behind it. Or you could adjust the image asset you’re using to by reversing the transparency. Or you could use `CoreImage` to do that in code. For example:

```
func invertMask(_ image: UIImage) -> UIImage?
{
    guard let inputMaskImage = CIImage(image: image),
        let backgroundImageFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIConstantColorGenerator", withInputParameters: [kCIInputColorKey: CIColor.black]), 
        let inputColorFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIConstantColorGenerator", withInputParameters: [kCIInputColorKey: CIColor.clear]), 
        let inputImage = inputColorFilter.outputImage, 
        let backgroundImage = backgroundImageFilter.outputImage,
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIBlendWithAlphaMask", withInputParameters: [kCIInputImageKey: inputImage, kCIInputBackgroundImageKey: backgroundImage, kCIInputMaskImageKey: inputMaskImage]),
        let filterOutput = filter.outputImage,
        let outputImage = CIContext().createCGImage(filterOutput, from: inputMaskImage.extent) else { return nil }
    let finalOutputImage = UIImage(cgImage: outputImage)
    return finalOutputImage
}
```

Comment: Amazing! The only problem I have is that the imageView smaller is than the UIView so the mask only shows the inverted image with the cutout. How can I fix that?

Comment: I suppose the easiest thing is to set the `frame` of the `imageView` to be the same size as the view you’re masking and set the `contentMode` of the `imageView` to be `.scaleAspectFill` but it’s hard to know exactly what to do. Perhaps you could update your question with what you’d like to happen.