# How could I do the "opposite-masking" of UIImages in Swift using UIKit?

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, uikit

I have two UIImages - let's call them base and overhead. Their size is the same.

I need a UIImage that is made like this: when overhead's pixel is solid or semi-transparent, use clear pixel. When overhead's pixel is fully transparent, use the base's pixel.

I do see that there are solutions for the opposite effect - clear when overhead's pixels are transparent, base otherwise. What is the best way to combine images this way?

The result can be made while base is still generated (with UIGraphicsImageRenderer, using Context operations) - separate base is not needed.

Here's the example
Base
[image]

Overhead (the transparency looks grey here, sorry)
[image]

base with overhead drawn on top of it (some parts are transparent, some are not)
[image]

Desired result
[image]

Comment: Have you looked into [Accelerate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate)? See [`vImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vimage) and [this Kodeco tutorial](https://www.kodeco.com/19456196-swift-accelerate-and-vimage-getting-started).

Comment: It would help if you show us a "base" image, an "overhead" image (with various areas / levels of alpha), and what you want as the result.

Comment: I already have UIKit and CoreImage, can I do this simple operation without adding a new module, with conversion from one image to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` and make it a bit easier than using `CIFilter` ...

You said your "base" and "overhead" images will be the same size, so I grabbed the images you posted and made the gray circles transparent.

Base Image (white is opaque white, although it doesn't really matter):

[image]

Overhead Image (white is transparent):

[image]

We can use this extension:

```
extension UIImage {
    func invertMasked(with maskImg: UIImage) -> UIImage {
        let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        format.scale = self.scale
        
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: self.size, format: format)
        return renderer.image { ctx in
            self.draw(at: .zero)
            maskImg.draw(at: .zero, blendMode: .destinationOut, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
let maskedImage = baseImage.invertMasked(with: overheadImage)
```

Here's a quick example:

```
class InvMaskVC: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        guard let baseImage = UIImage(named: "baseImage"),
              let overheadImage = UIImage(named: "overheadImage")
        else {
            fatalError("Could not load images!")
        }
        
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 20.0
        
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leftAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
        ])
        
        
        let maskedImage = baseImage.invertMasked(with: overheadImage)
                
        [baseImage, overheadImage, maskedImage].forEach { img in
            let iView = UIImageView(image: img)
            iView.backgroundColor = .red
            iView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iView.widthAnchor, multiplier: img.size.height / img.size.width).isActive = true
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(iView)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Gives this output:

[image]

- Top image view holds `baseImage`
- Middle image view holds `overheadImage`
- Bottom image view holds `maskedImage`

Image views all have a red background, so we can see the frames (and see the transparency).

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do this using mask invertion from this question [UIView invert mask MaskView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46862753/uiview-invert-mask-maskview).
After combining this with CIFilter.blendWithAlphaMask(), the desired result was made. But is this the most efficient way?